# How to implement an ApplicationListener in DirectMessageListenerContainer

Tags: spring-rabbit

Can anyone please guide on how to programatically register an ApplicationListener in DirectMessageListenerContainer(spring rabbitmq) to handle the ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listener is not registered to the container; it is simply added as a `@Bean` to the Spring application context; the container publishes the event and Spring dispatches it to each registered listener.

**EDIT**

Don't put code in comments; they don't render well - always edit the question instead and add a comment that you have done so.

Creating containers like that means you will miss all the Spring goodness and injected dependencies; it's better to add a `DirectRabbitListenerContainerFactory` `@Bean` to the application context and use it to create containers - that way the event publisher will be injected.

You only need one listener; it will receive events from all containers.

If you are not using Spring at all (except spring-rabbit) then you need to satisfy all of the container's `...Aware` interfaces yourself and call `afterPropertiesSet()`.

In this case you would call `setApplicationEventPublisher()` with your custom publisher which will receive the event(s).

Comment: Thanks Gary!. As I am programatically declaring the container could you please let me know how I could add the ApplicationListener as a Bean to the Spring application context.

Comment: DirectMessageListenerContainer directMessageListenerContainer = new RabbitDirectMessageListenerContainer(cachingConnectionFactory);
directMessageListenerContainer.setQueueNames(Queue1);
directMessageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(messageListener);
....
....
directMessageListenerContainer.start();

Comment: Don't put code in comments; they don't render well -- see the edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Gary for your help and yes, will take of the comment part in future