# How to handle connect listener exceptions while connecting to rabbitMQ using DirectMessageListenerContainer

Tags: spring-rabbit

I am using DirectMessageListenerContainer from Spring RabbitMQ for connecting to RabbitMQ. Here how do I handle the listener exceptions while connecting.

Comment: You already answered this question when asking your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58370414/how-to-implement-an-applicationlistener-in-directmessagelistenercontainer). Use an `ApplicationListener` to consume a `ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks Gary!